# How to get the data response from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I just want to ask how can I preview the data from my ajax request? I just want to know if the data is correct.

Here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var globalBase_Url = "{$base_url}" + "index.php/user_controller/processAdd/";   

            //alert(globalBase_Url);

            {literal}

                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#add_cat').on('click',function(){
                        $('#add_category').show('slide');
                    });

                    $('#submit').on('click',function(){

                        var name = $('#category_name').val();
                        var desc = $('#description').val();

                        console.log(globalBase_Url);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: globalBAse_Url,
                            data: {cat_name:name,cat_desc:desc}, //How can I preview this?
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async: false,
                            success: function(d){

                            }
                        });

                    });

                });

            {/literal}


        </script>
```

In my controller I have this.

```
public function processAdd(){

        $cat_name = $this->input->post('cat_name');
        $cat_desc = $this->input->post('cat_desc');



 }
```

I used the chrome developer tools and preview it's response in XHR. But I don't see my data. By the way I am using CodeIgniter

Comment: Are you directing it straight to your model? That's not a good plan let the controller receive your ajax then process it

Comment: Ok.. I will move the function in my controller. But how can I know if my data is received by the controller function?

Comment: in your controller put something like this `if($this->input->post)` also remember to add echo `json_encode($array)` so you can get a result from your ajax

Comment: Sorry im new in ajax. in json_encode is it the same as displaying the varible in PHP? or the data from my ajax is the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your controller:

you should have something like this

```
public function processAdd(){


  if($this->input->post()){

   //do something
   $var1 = $this->input->post('cat_name');
   $var2 = $this->input->post('cat_desc');

   echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok')); //must be encode with array to access it in your response as an object since you use DataType:json
  }

}
```

then in your ajax, to access the response

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/controllers/processAdd',
  data: {cat_name:name,cat_desc:desc}, //How can I preview this?
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false, //This is deprecated in the latest version of jquery must use now callbacks
  success: function(d){
   alert(d.status); //will alert ok
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok I just need to include json_encode() thanks for the reponse. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the browser developer tools > NetWork

Chrome: [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) 
FireFox: [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) - [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)/[Fire Bug](https://getfirebug.com/) -> [Network](https://getfirebug.com/network)

or

in the ajax success handler, log the data to the console

```
success: function(d){
    console.log(d);// then look at the developer tools -> console
}
```

Comment: Ok I have an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: globalBAse_Url is not defined. Do I need to re-declare my variable?

Comment: I am calling a 3rd party SMS API, but still, I am unable to receive the message delivery ID. But I can see the response of ID in Sources next to console but it is not found in console.log.  my code   ` $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'actualURL',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success: " + data.d);
                    console.log(data.d);
                }
            });`

Answer (score 1):

try putting

```
    var globalBase_Url = "{$base_url}" + "index.php/user_controller/processAdd/";
```

inside {literal} tag